# forEach is not a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

JS:

```
    function onAjaxSuccess(data){
    console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function(data) {
    table.innerHTML += getRowTemplate(data); }
    );
  }

function getRowTemplate(userData) {
    return '<tr>' +
                '<td>' +
                    userData.tovar +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    userData.type +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    userData.proizvoditel +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    userData.hvat +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    userData.ygol +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    userData.lengthc +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    userData.color +
                '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
       }
```

Что не так?

Содержимое data:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так results чему равно? Поставьте точку останова и посмотрите!

Comment: @PavelMayorov,   var results = JSON.stringify(data);
         results = JSON.parse(results);

Comment: @bsuart2017, зачем вы мучаете ваш бедный JSON, то в стринги его, то обратно? :) лучше посмотрите что у вас приходит в `data` и возьмите объект по названию, например, `data.price`, эти 2 строки что вы написали, можно удалить, и работать с data напрямую, ну или если хотите можно сделать `var results = data.price`, а дальше уже `results.forEach`, прайс если что взял для примера, мы не можем видеть что у вас там падает в data

Comment: @MasterAlex, изменил содержимое вопроса

Comment: могу предположить. что в `data` - строка, и нужна всего одна строка из двух: `var results = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: @Grundy, в data массив JSON

Comment: @bsuart2017, и тут ты не прав. Если бы это был _массив_ - не было бы ошибки _forEach is not a function_

Comment: @Grundy, добавил содержимое data

Comment: @Grundy, бывает такая ошибка, когда в data лежит объект :) сам сталкивался, а вот если взять этот объект, то внутри уже массив объектов

Comment: @bsuart2017, что еще раз подтверждает мой комментарий.

Comment: @MasterAlex, в данном случае все проще - data - это строка.

Comment: @bsuart2017, выведи в консоль `typeof data`, т.е. вместо `console.log(data);` сделай `console.log(typeof data);`

Comment: @Grundy, странная какая-то строка, если string, то почему не в одну строчку и не в кавычках :)

Comment: @Grundy, прав, выводит string, как ее преобразовать в нужный мне json?

Comment: @bsuart2017, прочитай мой самый первый комментарий, либо посмотри ответ :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, потому что это вывод `console.log`, и если в строке есть переносы строк - он их отлично отображает

Comment: @Grundy,уже даже попробовал, ошибка: Unexpected string in JSON

Comment: @bsuart2017, вставь получаемую строку текстом в вопрос, хотя я уже вижу ошибку

Comment: У тебя в `data` невалидный JSON, поэтому и разобрать ты его не можешь. Пропущена запятая после значения для поля `lengthc` в каждом элементе массива

Comment: @Grundy, точно(( работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> function onAjaxSuccess(data){
> ```

Добавь после этого

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```